# How to fix UnboundLocalError?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I have written a code....

```py
def setCaption(update,context):
  if update.message.reply_to_message is not None:
   fileCaption= update.message.text
   OwO = fileCaption.split(" ")
   c_id = OwO[-1]
   fileType=update.message.reply_to_message
  if c_id.startswith('@') or c_id.startswith('-'):
    if fileType.document!=None:
      update.message.send_document(chat_id = c_d, document = update.message.reply_to_message.document.file_id,caption=fileCaption, allow_sending_without_reply = True)
    elif fileType.video!=None:
      update.message.send_video(chat_id = c_id,video = update.message.reply_to_message.video.file_id,caption=fileCaption, allow_sending_without_reply = True)
    elif fileType.audio!=None:
      update.message.send_audio(chat_id = c_id, audio = update.message.reply_to_message.audio.file_id, caption=fileCaption, allow_sending_without_reply = True)
    elif fileType.voice!=None:
      update.message.send_voice(chat_id = c_id,
        voice = update.message.reply_to_message.voice.file_id,caption=fileCaption, allow_sending_without_reply = True)
    elif fileType.photo!=None:
      update.message.send_photo(chat_id = c_id, photo = update.message.reply_to_message.photo[-1].file_id,caption=fileCaption)
    else:
      update.message.reply_text(update.message.text)
    

  else:
    if fileType.document!=None:
      update.message.reply_document(
        update.message.reply_to_message.document.file_id,caption=fileCaption)
    elif fileType.video!=None:
      update.message.reply_video(
        update.message.reply_to_message.video.file_id,caption=fileCaption)
    elif fileType.audio!=None:
      update.message.reply_audio(
        update.message.reply_to_message.audio.file_id,caption=fileCaption)
    elif fileType.voice!=None:
      update.message.reply_voice(
        update.message.reply_to_message.voice.file_id,caption=fileCaption)
    elif fileType.photo!=None:
      update.message.reply_photo(update.message.reply_to_message.photo[-1].file_id,caption=fileCaption)
    else:
      update.message.reply_text(update.message.text)
```

when I am running the code I am getting following error:

```
File "/app/Setting_caption/caption.py", line 7, in setCaption
if c_id.startswith('@') or c_id.startswith('-'):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'c_id' referenced before assignment
No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
```

I am running the code via heroku

I tried to run my code and excepting that my bot will run but it is throwing error....

Comment: You must shift your second `if`-`else`-block under the first (for example). Or close the first by `else: return None`.

Comment: @Timus I see thank you, for the help sir